# String was not recognized as a valid Boolean Exception

Tags: c#, boolean, tostring, type-conversion

I'm converting my dataRow value into Boolean but getting the following exception:

> String was not recognized as a valid Boolean

This is the code:

```
bool a = Convert.ToBoolean(row["ISMOVING"].ToString());
```

`row["ISMOVING"]` contains 1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `row["ISMOVING"]`?

Comment: show us the value of row["ISMOVING"]. Probably it is not something that is supported by Boolean Converter.

Comment: Answer should be there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205436/convert-toboolean-fails-with-0-value

Comment: Why are you calling `ToString()` at all if you don't want to use the value as a string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert.ToBoolean fails with "0" value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205436/convert-toboolean-fails-with-0-value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove that `ToString()` call

```
bool a = Convert.ToBoolean(row["ISMOVING"]);
```

Comment: `row["ISMOVING"]` can also contain 'true'. Will it work then?

Comment: @HumaAli, have you tried? try first ... moreover what's your column type? is it `bit` or `vaechar`? can't be both right? edit your post and include those information first.

Comment: @HumaAli, BTW to answer you question ... Yes it will

Comment: Ok its `bit`. Thanks for your answer. It works

Answer (score -1):

row["ISMOVING"] should have any of these values"True","False","1"or "0" , any other values cannot be converted to bool also you dont have to convert it to string before converting it to bool.

Comment: This is incorrect. The `Convert.ToBoolean()` will convert any numeric value to a `bool` value, with `0` mapping to `false` and any other value mapping to `true`. It will not map any `string` value, except those parseable as `bool` (i.e. `"true"`, `"false"`, `"True"`, and `"False"`). See [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh2c31dd(v=vs.110).aspx) for the correct description of how the method works.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Also, `null` will be converted into `false` value.