# Convert bool to string in gridview item template

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to directly convert the booleans coming from my sqlserver database as bits to strings. Problem is, it says it is not valid as a boolean and i can't figure out why not since bit in sql is either 0 or 1

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Estado" SortExpression="EstadoInventario">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblEstadoArtigo" runat="server"

        CssClass='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("EstadoInventario").ToString())) ? "badge badge-success" : "badge badge-danger" %>'   
        Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("EstadoInventario").ToString())) ? "Aberto" : "Fechado" %>'>

         </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
```

I just want to show the text based on it's value and change class as well

Comment: Try to use `<%= Eval("EstadoInventario") %>` first. What do you get from there, a `true`/`false` string or something else?

Comment: it shows a 1 or 0, its strange cause in a previous project it showed true or false, but that was in a repeater and here im using gridview

Comment: How about using `<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("EstadoInventario").ToString())) ? ... : ... %>`? You need to convert with `Convert.ToBoolean` for numeric representation.

Comment: OH I see,  this worked, thanks! Althought it worked only without tostring

Comment: `Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("EstadoInventario"))` should work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `Eval()` function returns either "1" or "0" string instead of `true` or `false` which required by `bool.Parse()` method, you need to convert it into numeric representation before using `Convert.ToBoolean()`, or simply use `Convert.ToBoolean()` directly with `Eval("EstadoInventario")` without `ToString()`:

```
<%-- alternative 1 --%>

<asp:Label ID="lblEstadoArtigo" runat="server"
           CssClass='<%# (Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("EstadoInventario").ToString()))) ? "badge badge-success" : "badge badge-danger" %>'   
           Text='<%# (Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("EstadoInventario").ToString()))) ? "Aberto" : "Fechado" %>'>
</asp:Label>

<%-- alternative 2 --%>

<asp:Label ID="lblEstadoArtigo" runat="server"
           CssClass='<%# (Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("EstadoInventario"))) ? "badge badge-success" : "badge badge-danger" %>'   
           Text='<%# (Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("EstadoInventario"))) ? "Aberto" : "Fechado" %>'>
</asp:Label>
```

Related issue:

[Convert.ToBoolean fails with "0" value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205436/convert-toboolean-fails-with-0-value)